# Toggle #ID from child component

Tags: angular

Im using Angular 7 and I simply need to toggle a SideNav from a TopBar thats is inside SideNav Component.

Searching on stack and google I've found a lot of complicated solution about service component or strange listener.

SideNav Component

```
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="over" role="navigation">
    <mat-nav-list>
        <a mat-list-item routerLink='/first'>Link A</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content>

    <app-header></app-header>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

  </mat-sidenav-content>
```

AppHeader Component

```
<mat-toolbar class="labs-header" color="primary" >
  <mat-toolbar-row>
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
   [...]
```

If all  component code is directly inside SideNav, it works. With a sub-component it obviously lost #sidenav reference so .toggle() will fail.

Is there a method to bind the mat-sidenav component and pass to the child or maybe create a toggle function in sidenav component and than calling it from the child?

Comment: what do you mean by strange listeners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

header component should have an `@Output` that will emit on your click event :

```
(click)="toggleSidenav.emit()"
```

In the parent, you can listen for changes and toggle the sidenav accordingly :

```html
<mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="over" role="navigation">
    <mat-nav-list>
        <a mat-list-item routerLink='/first'>Link A</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content>

    <app-header (toggleSidenav)="sidenav.toggle()"></app-header>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

  </mat-sidenav-content>
```

This is the cleanest way, as it doesn't thightly couples your components. If someone tells you to

> Inject the sidenav into your header component

Don't listen to it, as it makes your components less reusable.

Comment: Thanks. It works. For the other people that may need, in app-header you need to istantiate the emitter with: `@Output() toggleSidenav = new EventEmitter<boolean>();`

Answer (score 0):

In your AppHeaderComponent.ts:

```
@Output() toggle = new EventEmitter();
```

In your AppHeaderComponent.html:

```
    <mat-toolbar class="labs-header" color="primary" >
     <mat-toolbar-row>
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="toggle.emit()">
        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
```

In your SideNavComponent.ts :

```
    @Viewchild('sideNav') sideNav;

   onToggle(){
     //toggle the sideNav
   }
```

In your SideNavComponent.Html:

```
<mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="over" role="navigation">
        <mat-nav-list>
            <a mat-list-item routerLink='/first'>Link A</a>
        </mat-nav-list>
      </mat-sidenav>

      <mat-sidenav-content>

        <app-header (toggle)= onToggle()></app-header> // or do it directly in template : sideNav.toggle() instead calling onToggle()

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

  </mat-sidenav-content>
```